# How can I change the hover icon for API groups in the API Store?

Tags: html, hover, wso2, icons, wso2-api-manager

In the API Store, if you hover over one of the API groups, the icon of an eye appears. Is there a way to customize the hover icon according to the group?

[This is the current store.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHytS.png)

[This is the proposed store.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYF4E.png)

Since the groups are generated, I couldn't find where in the code to assign specific icons to specific groupings. I thought that maybe it might be good to attach icons to the tags of the groups, but that's just an idea. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

We can assign icons to API groups through registry. Please see the documentation for details, https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Customizing+the+API+Store#CustomizingtheAPIStore-CategorizingandgroupingAPIs

Comment: Thank you for replying! Unfortunately, by your documentation, I can only assign thumbnail images to API groups. However, I want to use that same method of assigning thumbnail images to assign the icons. I've already found the source code to change the hover icon (located in themes/wso2/templates/api/api-listing-tag-wise/template.jag) but I want to be able to upload a specifically titled file (like icon.png) for each API Group in the carbon admin console and for that icon to show respectively.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding how to pull that icon.png URL, since it's specialized for each API Group. It should be the same as to how the thumbnail.png is being pulled, but I can't seem to track down the file to edit to include the function for icon.png.